# How Do I Move a Post iframe outside the Post Body in Blogger?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, blogger

I want to be able to take the first iframe used in my blog posts, and move it outside of the post body and into a div I created called #myvideos. I've seen blog templates like [this one](http://tubemag-themexpose.blogspot.com/2014/06/big-game.html) accomplish this, moving a video out of the post body. This is what I want to do with my own template: https://taylorduane.blogspot.com/2017/12/blog-post_58.html

This is the JQuery:

```
<script>
// <![CDATA[
$(function() {
if($("#bigframe").length>0) {

var bigvideo = $("#bigframe").attr("src");
var videotag = '<iframe src="'+bigvideo+'" id="covervideo" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
$(videotag).appendTo("#myvideo");
$("#bigframe").remove();
}
else {
$("#myvideo,#post-right").remove();
}

});

// ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hide the first iframe in the post body to prevent it from flicking then move it.

```html
<style type="text/css">
 .post-body #bigframe { display:none; }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myvideo"></div>

<div class="post-body">
<iframe id="bigframe" frameborder="0" height="281" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/14592941" width="500"></iframe>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#bigframe').appendTo('#myvideo');
</script>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a ton!